# Alert notification to the owner of the site

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Is there a way to set alert or some type notification that alerts the owner of the site when a new person is added to the site(when permission is given to a new user)

Comment: Said's answer is a good choice. You might be surprised at how many ways a user can be added to a a site's user list other than intentionally granting them access. An alert on that data would quickly become inbox chaff.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following tool :
https://lightningtools.com/permissions/sharepoint-permissions-auditing-and-alerts/

Otherwise, if you are limited to OOB features, you can at least audit it SPS 2010:

In site collection root site, `Site Actions` -> `Site Settings` -> `Site Collection Administration` -> `Audit log reports` -> `Security settings`, we can see the permission audit log report.

Before viewing the audit log report, it is needed to specify the `Editing users and permissions` events to audit.

In site collection root site, `Site Settings` -> `Site Collection Administration` -> `Site collection audit settings`, check the `Editing users and permissions` option.

After doing this, the changes to permissions on sites, lists and items will be audited in audit log report.

This is a link about viewing audit log reports for your reference:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx#_Toc272842196

Regards,

Saïd

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate auditing on the SharePoint server and track every change happens on the SharePoint server. Please refer to the following article

http://blog.ciaops.com/2015/04/enabling-sharepoint-online-auditing.html

http://sharepointauditing.blogspot.in/

Also check the below earlier threads:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8b974b21-01f3-487b-b581-b6026b867c81/alerts-for-when-permissions-change?forum=sharepointadminlegacy